# Escape characters when generating Powershell scripts using C#

Tags: c#, powershell, escaping, stringescapeutils

I use VS2010, C#, .NET 3.5 for generate Powershell scripts (ps1 files).

Then, it is required escape characters for Powershell.

Any suggestions about it for develop good method that escape characters?

```
  public static partial class StringExtensions
    {
        /*
        PowerShell Special Escape Sequences

        Escape Sequence         Special Character
        `n                      New line
        `r                      Carriage Return
        `t                      Tab
        `a                      Alert
        `b                      Backspace
        `"                      Double Quote
        `'                      Single Quote
        ``                      Back Quote
        `0                      Null
        */

        public static string FormatStringValueForPS(this string value)
        {
            if (value == null) return value;
            return value.Replace("\"", "`\"").Replace("'", "`'");
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
var valueForPs1 = FormatStringValueForPS("My text with \"double quotes\". More Text");
var psString = "$value = \"" + valueForPs1  + "\";";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other option would be to use a regex:

```
private static Regex CharactersToEscape = new Regex(@"['""]"); // Extend the character set as requird


public string EscapeForPowerShell(string input) {
  // $& is the characters that were matched
  return CharactersToEscape.Replace(input, "`$&");
}
```

Note: you don't need to escape backslashes: PowerShell does not use them as escape characters. This makes writing regexes somewhat easier.

Comment: maybe the regex is `"['\"]"`? need to escape the extra `"`

Comment: @C.B. Note the use of a literal string (`@"…"`): you escape double quotes in a literal string by doubling them.