# emacs --eval from the powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, emacs

I'm having a problem while invoking emacs to eval some elisp from the windows powershell.It seems to be a problem with the usage of quotes, but I can't figure that out:

This is the command that I'm executing:

```
PS> emacs.exe --eval '(with-current-buffer "*scratch*" (insert "Hi"))'
```

Then emacs opens and I get the following message in the *Backtrace* buffer:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable *scratch*)
(set-buffer *scratch*)
(save-current-buffer (set-buffer *scratch*) (insert Hi))
(with-current-buffer *scratch* (insert Hi))
eval((with-current-buffer *scratch* (insert Hi)))
command-line-1(("--eval" "(with-current-buffer *scratch* (insert Hi))"))
command-line()
normal-top-level()
```

Any help on how to run this correctly would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: @JordonBiondo I don't see a way how can the quotes can be escaped here. Any suggestion?

Comment: @quicoju It looks like [this](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html) has all the information you could possibly need. Also, SO has a couple of [related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19862232/1199226) [posts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18116186/1199226) about escaping quotes in PowerShell...

Comment: What is `*scratch*`? Why in asterisks? The error says that var is void.

Comment: @Vesper That is the buffer's name, emacs should see this string as "\*scratch\*", but for some reason powershell isn't passing the double quotes to emacs.

Comment: After playing a while with the quotes, I realized that I need to pass the emacs' escape character for the double quotes. So the command that finally worked for me is:

PS> emacs.exe --eval '(with-current-buffer \"*scratch*\" (insert \"Hi\"))'

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing a while with the quotes, I realized that I need to pass the emacs' escape character for the double quotes. So the command that finally worked for me is:

```
PS> emacs.exe --eval '(with-current-buffer \"*scratch*\" (insert \"Hi\"))'
```

Thanks everyone for your help.