# quote in quote in quote C# variable strings

Tags: c#, string, quotes

I have this line of code

```
"$FTE = Get-DynamicDistributionGroup '" + Input.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
```

And if my selected item is `daddy` then the output would be

```
Get-DynamicDistributionGroup 'daddy'
```

However is my item is `daddy's`

then the string has an extra '

```
Get-DynamicDistributionGroup 'daddy's'
```

How should I format this so that the `"` or `'` contains the apostrophe I tried a few ideas but none seem to work for all occasions.

Comment: @Yuck That might not be a duplicate because the OP is apparently generating a powershell script with C# and wants to escape quotes according to powershell rules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape characters when generating Powershell scripts using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15245119/11683)

Comment: Also see this: http://serverfault.com/questions/47811/what-is-the-literal-escape-character-in-powershell

Comment: Indeed the first answer suggested does not work for putting quotes around the input.selecitem.text variable when inserting it in to the string. Or at least I cant get it to

Comment: OK it was a bit of trial and error as some combinations the power shell did not like in the end i put + "\"" + at the ends of each string and it finally seemed to accept it.